# Showing that $G\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial b}\right) F(b) = F\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\left[G(x) e^{xb} \right]\Big|_{x=0}$

Tags: derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion, products

We want to show that

\begin{align*}
  G\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial b}\right) F(b) = F\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\left[G(x) e^{xb} \right]\Big|_{x=0} \tag{1}
\end{align*}

By assuming that the functions $F$ and $G$ are expandable in a convergent power series around $0$.

As we are assuming that $F$ and $G$ can be Taylor expanded we have

\begin{align*}
G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g_n x^n, \qquad F(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} f_m x^m
\end{align*}

Hence, the LHS of $(1)$ is given by

\begin{equation*}
G\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \right) F(b) = \sum_{n}^{\infty} \sum_{m}^{\infty} g_n \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial b}\right)^n f_m b^m \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

And the RHS of $(1)$ by

\begin{equation*}
F\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right) \left[ G(x) e^{xb}\right]\Big|_{x=0} = \sum_{n}^{\infty} \sum_{m}^{\infty} f_m \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^m \left[g_n x^n e^{xb}\right]\Big|_{x=0} \tag{3}
\end{equation*}

The issue is that I do not see how to show equality between $(2)$ and $(3)$. It looks like I should use the product rule on (3) but I do not see how the result would lead to show the equality.